# Appending to an tar archive removes everything else

Tags: linux, append, tar

Why is it that appending the a tar archive removes everything else?

```
[jalal@adelie-07] (23)$ tar zcvf tar_new.tar.gz new_file 
new_file
[jalal@adelie-07] (24)$ tar -tvf tar_new.tar.gz 
-rw-rw-r-- jalal/jalal       0 2016-02-03 00:20 new_file
```

Basically how can I add a single file to a tar file without removing everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append a new file in a compressed tar file. We can add a file to existing simple tar file with option '-r' instead of '-c'.

```
$ ls
a  b
$ tar -cvf tar_new.tar a b
a
b
$ tar -tvf tar_new.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- guest/guest 0 2016-02-03 12:17 a
-rw-rw-r-- guest/guest 0 2016-02-03 12:17 b
$ touch newfile
$ tar -rvf tar_new.tar newfile 
newfile
$ tar -tvf tar_new.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- guest/guest 0 2016-02-03 12:17 a
-rw-rw-r-- guest/guest 0 2016-02-03 12:17 b
-rw-rw-r-- guest/guest 0 2016-02-03 12:18 newfile
$ gzip tar_new.tar 
$ ls
a  b  newfile  tar_new.tar.gz
$
```